# How can I add a current background color to each new div I create via Javascript when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

sorry its a bit of a confusing question.
I am working on a Javascript problem that has multiple parts, i believe i solved all of them except for the last step:

Every time i press "Click Me" button, my background color, color's name and background color of the "click me" button changes randomly using an array of colors. It also creates a square (its a div via .innerHTML in JS).  I want to add another function, when i click the "click me" button, i would like to keep adding more boxes and each box that is added inherits the same background color as the  at the time of the click. As i keep pressing the button, those squares stay with their background colors, and new ones continue to be created with the with the changing background.

I apologize if the description is confusing and thank you so much for your time!

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bgcolor">
    <h1>Background Color : <span id="color">Red</span></h1>
    </div>
    <button id="click">click me</button>
    <div id="squares"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 100px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
}

button {
    padding: .5em 1.5em;
    font-size: 60px;
    border: 7px solid black ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}


#bgcolor {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    
}

#squares {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

#test {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
```

Javascript

```
const colorChange = document.querySelector('#color');
const click = document.querySelector('#click');
const squares = document.querySelector('#squares');
let cubes = [];


const defaultBackground = 'lightgray';


// Set default background color and color name to uppger case when the page loads
document.body.style.backgroundColor =  defaultBackground;
colorChange.textContent = defaultBackground[0].toUpperCase() + defaultBackground.substring(1);
colorChange.style.color = defaultBackground;
click.style.backgroundColor = defaultBackground;

// Colors

const colors = ["red", "beige", "burlywood", "coral", "aqua", "darkcyan", "pink", "lawngreen", "fuchsia"];

click.addEventListener('click', function samecolor() {
  
  
    // Random Color Selector
 const ranColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];  

//  If statement to ensure that some color does not repeat two times in a row.
// Statement reads if background color already displayed doesn't equal to the random color selected, then display
// that color. Do the same for color name and button background.

 if (document.body.style.backgroundColor != ranColor 
        && colorChange.style.color != ranColor 
            && click.style.backgroundColor != ranColor) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ranColor; 
    colorChange.style.color = ranColor; 
    click.style.backgroundColor = ranColor;
    // If all the conditions above are met, also display the name of the random color selected with upper case first letter.
    colorChange.textContent = ranColor[0].toUpperCase() + ranColor.substr(1);
 } else  {
    samecolor()
 }
 
 
 function work() {
 squares.innerHTML += `<div id="test"> </div>`
 document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = ranColor;
 }
 work()
 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in a playground: [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cache-188tl0?file=/src/styles.css)

```js
const colorChange = document.querySelector("#color");
const click = document.querySelector("#click");
const squares = document.querySelector("#squares");
let cubes = [];

const defaultBackground = "lightgray";

// Set default background color and color name to uppger case when the page loads
document.body.style.backgroundColor = defaultBackground;
colorChange.textContent =
  defaultBackground[0].toUpperCase() + defaultBackground.substring(1);
colorChange.style.color = defaultBackground;
click.style.backgroundColor = defaultBackground;

// Colors

const colors = [
  "red",
  "beige",
  "burlywood",
  "coral",
  "aqua",
  "darkcyan",
  "pink",
  "lawngreen",
  "fuchsia"
];

let currentColor = null;

function changeColor() {
  // Random Color Selector
  const ranColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

  // If color is the same as the previous one, it calls itself again
  if (currentColor === ranColor) {
    changeColor();
    return;
  }
  // Sets the current color so that we don't repeat it
  currentColor = ranColor;

  // Change the colors
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ranColor;
  colorChange.style.color = ranColor;
  click.style.backgroundColor = ranColor;
  colorChange.textContent = ranColor[0].toUpperCase() + ranColor.substr(1);

  // Add a square with that color
  const newSquare = document.createElement("div");
  newSquare.style.backgroundColor = ranColor;
  newSquare.className = "test";
  squares.append(newSquare);
}

click.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

Some points worth mentioning:

- In CSS, if you have an ID `#test` it should only be on the page once, otherwise it's best to use a classname. I've changed your `#test` to `.test`
- I simplified your `if` statement with a variable `currentColor`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to go over it. I am reading it  now and trying to understand your schedule. I apologize, I am fairy new to Javascript.  Is createElement() and .append a better way to write HTML in JS? I am not too familiar with it, i thought you could just use innerHTML. Do you advice learning it?   Thank you for showing me how easy it was to actually make that IF statement.   So you are basically able to create a new DIV and set its background color simply by just creating newSquare?   newSquare is created everytime you run the function. Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Also, i am fairly new to stackoverflow. Do i need to press something to give you more reputation or thank you for helping me?

Comment: In the left hand side of my question, you should see an up and down arrow with a counter and also a check mark. Click the check mark to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: Using `createElement` and `append` are pretty common methods in Javascript. You can find out more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement